# Symfony 2 FOSUserBundle Anonymous after login

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle, propel

I'm implementing FOSUserBundle on a Symfony 2.5 install. 
I have two problems:

1. ***(SOLVED) When I login I get redirected to the debugger page, I have no idea why. Shouldn't I be directed to the last page I was trying to access without valid credentials? (SOLVED)***
2. The debugger says that I'm logged in, but as Anonymous user with no roles. That is strange, since the page has the "ROLE_USER" role (and so does the user)

When I ***var_dump($this->getUser())*** I get a full user object (with the actual user that i've logged in!)

**$this->getUser() Object:**

```
object(FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User)#244 (33) {
  ["plainPassword":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["startCopy":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["id":protected]=>
  int(4)
  ["username":protected]=>
  string(4) "user"
  ["username_canonical":protected]=>
  string(4) "user"
  ["email":protected]=>
  string(15) "user@domain.com"
  ["email_canonical":protected]=>
  string(15) "user@domain.com"
  ["enabled":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["salt":protected]=>
  string(31) "gfxdkl84d0ook0k8wow4c8s4w4owk8g"
  ["password":protected]=>
  string(88) "wYA5nYGe1vQYiiWIB9z9eFPlWG2V/BEts/60wbuwiL34FzDtFyb9TExNOpvbKL4DFt3Ruvm9+f2HW1mx850+Aw=="
  ["last_login":protected]=>
  string(19) "2014-07-22 12:55:25"
  ["locked":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["expired":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["expires_at":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["confirmation_token":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["password_requested_at":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["credentials_expired":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["credentials_expire_at":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["roles":protected]=>
  string(13) "| ROLE_USER |"
  ["roles_unserialized":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["collUserGroups":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["collUserGroupsPartial":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["collGroups":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["alreadyInSave":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["alreadyInValidation":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["alreadyInClearAllReferencesDeep":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["groupsScheduledForDeletion":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["userGroupsScheduledForDeletion":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["validationFailures":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_new":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_deleted":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["modifiedColumns":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["virtualColumns":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

**security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/.*
            provider: fos_userbundle
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
            anonymous: true        

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

**config.yml**

```
...
# FOS
fos_user:
    db_driver: propel
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User
...
```

I'm new to Symfony, so I'm a bit lost.

Thanks in advance

**Question 1 SOLVED**:

In the login form twig template, I added:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="g9_bo_homepage" />
```

This is the redirect page after login.

Comment: Post your app/... security.yml file or at least the fosuser part of it

Comment: I think `provider: fos_userbundle` should be under the form_login: node

Comment: Have you installed the TypehintableBehavior considering you're using propel?

Comment: Yes I did @user2071225